# Unexpected modification in pandas df after setting index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am starting working with pandas and I have encountered a problem.
I am working with different csvs which have the form:

```
10,152.46
12,124.67
11,150.1
20/21,126.7
37/38,128.8
39,6.19
40,6.8
35-36,9.7
27-31_32,11.3
```

To Import it, I run:
`experimental = pd.read_csv(csv_file,usecols=[0,1]).dropna()` --> works as expected

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 152.46 |
| 1 | 12 | 124.67 |
| 2 | 11 | 150.1 |
| 3 | 20/21 | 126.7 |
| 4 | 37/38 | 128.8 |
| 5 | 39 | 6.19 |
| 6 | 40 | 6.8 |
| 7 | 35-36 | 9.7 |
| 8 | 27-31_32 | 11.3 |

then, to easily combine it with other df
experimental = experimental.set_index(experimental.columns[0])

And here is where the problem starts. With some other files that look the same, there is no problem: no more index and the second column (10/12/11...) are set as index.
This would be the expected results, same as observed with other csv files

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 152.46 |
| 12 | 124.67 |
| 11 | 150.1 |

However, with others (like this), I get this type of df

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
|  | 152.46 |
| 10 |  |
| 12 | 124.67 |
| 11 | 150.1 |

...

I have tried reading as utf-8 or adding a header in the csv without success.
In the way I am presenting it, other files that look the same work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting a correct index: `experimental.columns[0]` returns the name of the first column. To set the first column as an index use

```
experimental.set_index(experimental.iloc[:, 0])
```

Alternatively, you can use `index_col=0` in `pd.read_csv` to set the first column as the index upon reading:

```
experimental = pd.read_csv(csv_file, usecols=[0,1], index_col=0, header=None).dropna()
```

The `header=None` keyword indicates that your data does not have any column names and that the first row in your csv is the first data row.

Comment: Thx for the fast answer. Unfortunately with both code lines, the problem persist. There is that "blank" cell that persists :(

Comment: @user1997194 Did you use `header=None`? What is the output of `experimental.columns`? The 'blank' cell is just a visual separator for the column names and the index name. Your data looks like the name of your columns is `10` and `152.46`.

Comment: Yes. I copied and paste it.
the results of print(experimental.columns)
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')

Maybe I should have mentioned that I easily realize the error when i run:
noc = [f for f in list(experimental.index) if '-' not in f]
and then the error is 'float' is not iterable